# Why do Clojure numbers end with "N" in the REPL?

Tags: clojure

So, I grabbed the latest numeric tower for a couple quick calculations and noticed that the numbers returned have "N" at the end.  Why?  What does it mean?

```
clojure.math.numeric-tower=> (expt 64 20)
1329227995784915872903807060280344576N
clojure.math.numeric-tower=> (expt 36 20)
13367494538843734067838845976576N
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is the literal form of `BigInt`:

```
user=> (type 1N)
clojure.lang.BigInt
```

versus, for example:

```
user=> (type 1)
java.lang.Long
```

or

```
user=> (type 1.0)
java.lang.Double
```

There's also the `M` suffix for `BigDecimal`.

```
user=> (type 1M)
java.math.BigDecimal
```

I'm not sure of all the rules for promotion to arbitrary precision (BigInt, BigDecimal).  I think most of the "regular" math functions won't promote to arbitrary precision, but there are a few that do (e.g. `+'`, `-'`, `*'`, `inc'`, `dec'`).

e.g. Regular `+` overflows:

```
user=> (+ Long/MAX_VALUE 1)
ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1388)
```

but `+'` promotes:

```
user=> (+' Long/MAX_VALUE 1)
9223372036854775808N
```